# Nested attributes in FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'd like to know if there's a way to set nested attributes using Angular 2's FormBuilder, something like this:

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required],

  address: {
     state: ['ca', Validators.required],   // <---- this gives an error
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ion-item-divider color="light">Personal Data</ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>State</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="address.state"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

This gives me an error saying that it couldn't find an field name `state`, even though it is there.

This would help me a lot, because I have a very long form and it would be good to organize it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can show your template that will help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: added the template on the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sasxa was halfway in his answer but missed that you were seeing the error in the template evaluation portion. Hence why posting the template was important.

To fix it you wrap your address portion of the template in some unobtrusive element like:

```
<span formGroupName="address">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>State</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="state"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
</span>
```

and when you're building the form do as was suggested:

```
address: formBuilder.group({
   state: ['ca', Validators.required]
})
```

Doc for [FormGroupName](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroupName-directive.html)

Comment: is `span` the best approach? I think i'm gonna use `ion-item-group`.

Comment: @AlexandreJ. I chose span figuring it would minimize impact, if it works with `ion-item-group` then go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required],

  address: formBuilder.group({
     state: ['ca', Validators.required],
  }),
});
```

and in template:

```
<ion-input type="text" [formControl]="address.get('state')"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Because he's probably not also specifying a `formGroupName` in the template so it's looking for "form -> state" instead of "form -> address -> state"

Comment: @AlexandreJ. Can you provide plunker with an example?

Comment: @silentsod so I would need to create two forms?

Comment: @AlexandreJ. no, just add that directive in your template

Comment: Where would it go?